# Fetch only first specific bytes of an image URL to create a placeholder (browser)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I want to fetch only 1300 bytes of an image from a URL to create a placeholder before the image is completely loaded. I tried using `XMLHttpRequest` and `progress` event (for a 2.12KB image)

```js
 req.addEventListener("progress", (ev) => {
        console.log("loaded bytes", ev.loaded); // 2179
    })
```

but the first time the event triggers `ev.loaded` is 2179 so the whole file has got already downloaded (I don't want it!). That being said, when I tried Python `requests` with stream mode and declaring `chunk_size`, that 1300 bytes were successfully written into the file without any problem:

```py
with requests.get(url , stream=True) as response:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1300):
        print(len(chunk)) # 1300
        with open("test.jpg" , "wb") as f:
            f.write(chunk)
            break
```

[image]

Assuming the server does not accept the `Range` header, is there a way to do so with any API in the browser?

Comment: I don't understand how you plan to create a *"placeholder"* of an image by just loading the first part of an image?.. On the other hand, if you loaded already the entire image, than... just show it. Ugly-placeholders are usually already present on the server, max 50kB image, ugly and pixelated, you load that one first and show it while waiting for the 10MB one to be fully loaded.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I want to create a blurry image with those first bytes, not a clear placeholder, via [blurhash](https://github.com/woltapp/blurhash), I want the placeholder to be shown as fast as possible rendered on the client side before the image.

Comment: You could provide an option to request only the first part of the image, such as with a URL parameter `partial=1`. On the server you deliver just the first N bytes of the image if that query parameter is set. In the browser, issue two requests simultaneously, one with, and one without the partial parameter. If the partial response arrives first show the partial image

Comment: @PeterThoeny I don't have access to the server. I want a solution for any image URL